# Prevent __start entry point from being optimized out

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

With the following `CFLAGS`:

```
-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -O3 -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
```

my `__start` entry point (notice `-nostartfiles`) is successfully compiled and put into an output executable.

However, when I add `-flto` flag, both the entry point and functions called by it only are optimized out. Moreover, the following linking is performed with neither error nor warning, but with incorrect (random) entry point.

**A question is** how to prevent `__start` function from being optimized out. It`s also interesting for me why a linker “forgets” about an external dependency on *my* entry point in lack of the default one.

My GCC version is *gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2*.

---

**UPD:**

Source code (fixed with help of [@FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl), who wrote about prepended underscores in Windows ABI):

```
#include <windows.h>

void _start()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello world."), TEXT(""), MB_OK);
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Assembly output emitted by a linker (`-S`):

1. Non-`-flto` version:

   ```
   Disassembly of section .text:

   00401000 <__start>:
     401000:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
     401003:       c7 44 24 0c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esp)
     40100a:       00
     40100b:       c7 44 24 08 00 20 40    movl   $0x402000,0x8(%esp)
     401012:       00
     401013:       c7 44 24 04 0d 20 40    movl   $0x40200d,0x4(%esp)
     40101a:       00
     40101b:       c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
     401022:       ff 15 54 40 40 00       call   *0x404054
     401028:       83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
     40102b:       c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
     401032:       ff 15 4c 40 40 00       call   *0x40404c
     401038:       90                      nop
     401039:       90                      nop
     40103a:       90                      nop
     40103b:       90                      nop
     40103c:       90                      nop
     40103d:       90                      nop
     40103e:       90                      nop
     40103f:       90                      nop

   00401040 <__CTOR_LIST__>:
     401040:       ff                      (bad)
     401041:       ff                      (bad)
     401042:       ff                      (bad)
     401043:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     401045:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
           ...

   00401048 <__DTOR_LIST__>:
     401048:       ff                      (bad)
     401049:       ff                      (bad)
     40104a:       ff                      (bad)
     40104b:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     40104d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   ```
2. `-flto` version (notice the lack of `_start` here, just a bunch of thunks for API entries):

   ```
   Disassembly of section .text:

   00401000 <_ExitProcess@4>:
     401000:       ff 25 4c 30 40 00       jmp    *0x40304c
     401006:       90                      nop
     401007:       90                      nop

   00401008 <_MessageBoxA@16>:
     401008:       ff 25 54 30 40 00       jmp    *0x403054
     40100e:       90                      nop
     40100f:       90                      nop

   00401010 <__CTOR_LIST__>:
     401010:       ff                      (bad)
     401011:       ff                      (bad)
     401012:       ff                      (bad)
     401013:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     401015:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
           ...

   00401018 <__DTOR_LIST__>:
     401018:       ff                      (bad)
     401019:       ff                      (bad)
     40101a:       ff                      (bad)
     40101b:       ff 00                   incl   (%eax)
     40101d:       00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   ```

Comment: Source, please.  Also, C or C++?  they aren't the same language.

Comment: Also, why do you want __start to be there? What's the problem with __start not being emitted?

Comment: have you tried adding `-Wl,-e__start` to force entrypoint?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that should not do anything, LTO happens in the compiler.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182338/how-can-i-force-gcc-to-compile-functions-that-are-not-used

Comment: Though, you are, right, there should be a bug report for this.

Comment: Required details are added.

Comment: @Arhad Did you try naming your entry point `_start` instead of `__start`? In the Windows ABI, the compiler implicitly adds a preceding underscore to C function names, so if your function is called `__start`, the symbol is actually `___start` which is wrong.

Comment: I have taken the wrong assembly output for non`-flto` case; fixed. After that, an idea of @FUZxxl about extra underscore became oblivious.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, your suggestion was absolutely correct, it works for me. Publish it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all the exotic/embedded-related options you've set, you have to ensure that your symbol is seen as your entrypoint and not garbage collected by linker optimizations (`--gc-sections` also does that: collecting "useless" sections)

You can end up with a fully empty `.elf` file since no section is reachable.

To tell the linker that you are using that symbol as an entrypoint (and avoid that the linker eludes it!), just add

`-Wl,-e__start`

option to your link command (or write a linker spec file where you declare your symbol, but the command line option is easier)